# Google Cloud Dataproc: cluster create errors (debconf DbDriver config.dat locked)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

Recently, I have experienced occasional errors while attempting to create dataproc clusters in GCP. The creation command is similar to:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
       --zone "us-east1-b" \
       --master-machine-type "n1-standard-16" \
       --master-boot-disk-size 150 \
       --num-workers ${WORKER_NODE_COUNT:-9} \
       --worker-machine-type "n1-standard-16" \
       --worker-boot-disk-size 25 \
       --project ${PROJECT_NAME}  \
       --properties 'yarn:yarn.log-aggregation-enable=true'
```

Very intermittently, the error I receive is:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create) Operation [projects/PROJECT/regions/global/operations/UUID] failed: Multiple Errors:
- Failed to initialize node random-name-m. See output in: gs://dataproc-UUID-us/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/UUID/random-name-m/dataproc-startup-script_output
- Failed to initialize node random-name-w-0. See output in: gs://dataproc-UUID-us/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/UUID/random-name-w-0/dataproc-startup-script_output
- Failed to initialize node random-name-w-1. See output in: gs://dataproc-UUID-us/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/UUID/random-name-w-1/dataproc-startup-script_output
- Worker random-name-w-8 unable to register with master random-name-m. This could be because it is offline, or network is misconfigured..
```

And the last lines of the Google Storage bucket output file (dataproc-startup-script_output) are:

```
+ debconf-set-selections
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
++ logstacktrace
++ local err=1
++ local code=1
++ set +o xtrace
ERROR: 'debconf-set-selections' exited with status 1
Call tree:
 0: /usr/local/share/google/dataproc/startup-script-cloud_datarefinery_image_20180803_nightly-RC04.sh:490 main
Exiting with status 1
```

This one is really starting to annoy me! Any ideas/thoughts/resolutions are much appreciated!

Comment: Most of the things variabled-out are potentially useful information. Please share things like number of workers, node sizes, disk sizes, region. Also, how frequently is this happening? Could you `clusters describe` the cluster and share imageVersion?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've updated my question.

Comment: Current cluster is `imageVersion: 1.2.45-deb8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix for this issue will be rolling out over the course of next week's release.
You can check the release notes to see when the fix has rolled out here:
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/release-notes

Comment: Could you elaborate more on:
- What the issue was?
- What the specific fix was?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing: when Dataproc creates a cluster, it runs a start-up script on each node that initializes a lot of the services on the cluster in parallel. Because of this, sometimes config.dat would be locked by another process. The fix wasn't anything fancy - we just retry debconf-set-selections with some backoff if another process has the lock. In this specific case, we were using debconf-set-selections to get past some prompts when we uninstall mariadb on worker nodes.

Comment: A quick update on this. The issue was fixed on Oct 5 - [config.dat is locked by another process](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/release-notes#october_5_2018).